# Rsyslog's imfile plugin not working on CentOS 7?

Tags: file, logging, plugins, centos7, rsyslog

I am trying to get *Rsyslog*'s `imfile` plugin working **without**
any real success.

Here is useful *OS* version information:

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

And here is *Rsyslog* version information:

```
# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 7.4.7, compiled with:
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
```

I tried **both** *legacy* and *RainerScript* format of the configuration.
None of them works for me, sadly. I must be doing something completely wrong
but I simply can not decide on what it could be.

Here is my actual *testing* configuration (in *RainerScript*, the
former *legacy* version I tested was exactly the same in it's meaning):

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
global(
    workDirectory = "/tmp"
) 

module(
    load = "imuxsock"
)

module(
    load = "imjournal"
    stateFile = "journal.state"
)

module(
    load = "imfile"
    pollingInterval = "10"
)

ruleset(name = "test-ruleset") {
    if $syslogtag contains "test-syslogtag" then {
        action(
            type = "omfile"
            file = "/tmp/test-file.log"
        )
        stop
    }
}

input(
    type = "imfile"
    tag = "test-syslogtag"
    stateFile = "test-input.state"
    facility = "daemon"
    severity = "debug"
    file = "/tmp/test-input.in"
    ruleset = "test-ruleset"
)

if prifilt("*.*") then {
    action(
        type = "omfile"
        file = "/tmp/rsyslog-testing.log"
    )
}
```

**No** warning nor error are produced by the *Rsyslog* with the above
configuration but also nothing from the `/tmp/test-input.in` file
is copied to the `/tmp/test-file.log`.

(I also double-checked the `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, of course, and ...
nothing suspicious is there. Being desperate on what's going on, I also
tried to `setenforce 0` to switch *SELinux* off completely and to restart
the *Rsyslog* afterwards. It did not helped so the root cause of the problem
may not be *SELinux*-related issue.)

Also, the `test-input.state` file is correctly created in the *global*
`workDirectory` path (`/tmp` in this *testing* case). I also tried
standard paths (logs in `/var/log`, state file in `/var/lib/rsyslog`)
and it does not work either although all related files were created properly.

What's weird: I can not see any change in the state file if I populate the
input log file with some testing data even after *Rsyslog* restart using
`# systemctl restart rsyslog` (it should update the state file by default).

Just to point out: the `imjournal` and `imuxsock` plugins work and populate the fallback log file `/tmp/rsyslog-testing.log` correctly. Also
manually running *Rsyslog* on foreground with `-D` and/or `-d` options
did not helped me much to clarify why the `imfile` plugin does not work
for me in this particular configuration.

So, could you please

1. check my *RainerScript* syntax whether there is no obvious fault (I guess there is no such),
2. show me some *working* `imfile` plugin configuration on *EL7*?

Thank you very much.

-- 
*mjf*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a few *minor* changes it finaly started to work properly. I think the
main root cause of the problem *in my case* must have been my testing it in
the `/tmp` directory where *Rsyslog* does not seem to work properly for some
reason on *CentOS 7*.

(May it be the `/tmp` is populated by the *File System Namespace* even
despite the fact that *Systemd* option `PrivateTmp` is not set to `true` in
the *Rsyslog* unit file and this option **should** be set to `false` by
default according to the *Systemd* manual page? This is higly unprobable, but
I haven't managed myself to dig more further into it yet. If I find it out,
I will update this answer.)

The other *minor* cause might have been incorrect filter written in
*RainerScript* (my real testing instance contained a **horrible typo** I
simply over-looked). So here is the resulting *testing* configuration that
works like charm for me.

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
global(
    workDirectory = "/var/lib/rsyslog"
)

module(
    load = "imuxsock"
)

module(
    load = "imjournal"
    stateFile = "journal.state"
)

module(
    load = "imfile"
    pollingInterval = "10"
)

ruleset(name = "test-ruleset") {
    if $programname == "test-syslogtag" then {
        action(
            type = "omfile"
            file = "/var/log/test-file.log"
        )
        stop
    }
}

input(
    type = "imfile"
    tag = "test-syslogtag:"
    stateFile = "test-input.state"
    facility = "daemon"
    severity = "debug"
    file = "/var/log/test-input.in"
    ruleset = "test-ruleset"
)

if prifilt("*.*") then {
    action(
        type = "omfile"
        file = "/var/log/rsyslog-testing.log"
    )
}
```

A little hint for those not knowing it - the `$syslogtag` and the
`$programname` seem to be close relatives: `$syslogtag := $programname ":"`.
You can easily find out all the `$` prefixed variables you can match against
by using `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` output template which is already compiled in.

I hope it helps.

-- 
*mjf*